# Prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

I have this object, `dive`:

```
var dive = new Foo.Bar();
```

And `Foo.Bar` looks like this:

```
var Foo = {
    Bar: function() {
        ...
        return function() {
        // do stuff, no return
        };
    }
};
```

I'd like `dive` to have all the prototypes of another, existing object, however. Let's say `window.Cow.prototype` is:

```
{
    moo: function() { ... },
    eat: function() { ... }
}
```

What do I need to do to `Foo.Bar` so that I can do this:

```
dive.moo();
dive.eat();
```

Comment: You do understand that the way your code works, `dive` itself is a function, right?

Comment: Why are you calling `Bar` as a constructor? It's defined to return a custom function... Or: Why does `Bar` return a custom function if it's a constructor?

Comment: Are you trying to create callable objects?

Comment: Yes, patrick, I would like to return a function, but a function that I can also call functions off of. So I could do: `dive()` or `dive.fn()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the start, jimbojw! You were close, but you gave me enough information to get it:

```
function Cow() {
    return {
        talk: function() {
             alert("mooo");   
        }
    };   
}

var Foo = {
    Bar: function() {
        function result() {
            alert("Foo.Bar says...");
        };
        result.prototype = new Cow();
        return new result;
    }
};

new Foo.Bar().talk();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Foo = {
    Bar: function() {
        //...
        return this; // technically unnecessary, implied by 'new' operator
    }
};

Foo.Bar.prototype = new Cow(); // the secret sauce

dive = new Foo.Bar();

dive.moo(); // moo's like a Cow
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example without the Bar constructor [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/Bm9VC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encapsulate `Foo.Bar.prototype =` you can do it without changing default constructor behavior:

```
function Cow() {
  this.talk =  function() {
    alert("mooo")
  }
}

var Foo = {
  Bar: function() {
    var constructor = function() {
      this.eat = function() {
        alert("gulp")
      }
    }
    constructor.prototype = new Cow()
    return constructor
  }()
}

var foo = new Foo.Bar()
foo.talk()
foo.eat()
```